# Using dataset.map function passes Tensor without values

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hello i'm using tensorflow 2.10 and struggling with tensorflow data api. I wrote the following simple piece of code:

```
def loaddata(filepath, label):
    data = np.load(filepath.numpy().decode())
    return data, label 

filenames = []
labels = []

/*appending some data into filenames and labels*/ 

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
dataset = dataset.map(loaddata)
```

However, i receive "AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'" error. I have search similar error but could not find effective way to pass tuples via dataset.map() function.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does `tensor.eval()` work instead?

Comment: no chance. receiving "eval is not supported when eager execution is enabled, is .numpy() what you're looking for?" error.

Comment: You need to use native tensorflow operations as tf.data map function executed in graph mode. Or you can wrap it with tf.py_function.

Comment: @Frightera can you provide me solution based on tf.py function wrapping based on code i provide?